# Different behaviour in multiline text when using Java instead of xml

Tags: java, android, android-layout

My problem is that a multiline text works properly in my xml template. If the text is wider than the screen it wraps into the next line. But if I try the same in Java, the text won't be wrapped:

I have the following xml template for testing my prospective layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    >
    <ScrollView 
            android:id="@+id/scrollView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">
    <TableLayout 
            android:id="@+id/messageTable"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:stretchColumns="*"
            android:clickable="false">
        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:background="#777777"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:clickable="false">
            <TextView 
                 android:id="@+id/topic"
                 android:text="This is the topic"            
                 android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:textSize="14sp"
                 android:paddingLeft="5sp"
                 android:paddingRight="5sp"
                 android:paddingTop="2sp"
                 android:paddingBottom="2sp"
                 android:textStyle="bold" 
                 android:clickable="false"  
                 />
        </TableRow>
         <TableRow>
            <TextView
                 android:text="Mo., 26.12.2011, 10:00 - This is some example text. It will be wrapped in view. This works."
                 android:textSize="14sp"
                 android:paddingLeft="5sp"
                 android:paddingRight="5sp"
                 android:paddingTop="2sp"
                 android:paddingBottom="2sp"
                 android:scrollHorizontally="false"
                 android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                 android:longClickable="false"
                 android:clickable="false"
                 android:layout_width="0sp"
                 />
        </TableRow>
.
.
.
```

Now I'd like to use parts of these xml in my Java code. The table rows should be generated dynamically, depending on the data I will receive in the real application. Now the xml of the real application looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    >
    <ScrollView 
            android:id="@+id/scrollView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">
    <TableLayout 
            android:id="@+id/messageTable"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:stretchColumns="*"
            android:clickable="false">
    </TableLayout>
.
.
.
```

In code I use own types for my text rows, text topics and text bodies:

TopicTableRow:

```
public class TopicTableRow extends TableRow {

    public TopicTableRow(Context context) {
        super(context);

        setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#777777"));
        setClickable(false);
    }
}
```

TopicTextView:

```
public class TopicTextView extends TextView {

    public final String TAG = "TopicTextView";

    public TopicTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        PixelCalc pixelCalc = new PixelCalc(context, TAG);

        setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        setPadding(pixelCalc.scaledPixelToPixel(5), pixelCalc.scaledPixelToPixel(2), pixelCalc.scaledPixelToPixel(5), pixelCalc.scaledPixelToPixel(2));

        setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
        setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 14f);
        setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);

        setClickable(false);
    }
}
```

and BodyTextView (which doesn't wrap the text) looks like this:

```
public class BodyTextView extends TextView {

    public final String TAG = "BodyTextView";

    public BodyTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        PixelCalc pixelCalc = new PixelCalc(context, TAG);

        setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        setPadding(pixelCalc.scaledPixelToPixel(5), pixelCalc.scaledPixelToPixel(2), pixelCalc.scaledPixelToPixel(5), pixelCalc.scaledPixelToPixel(2));

        setClickable(false);
        setLongClickable(false);

        setHorizontallyScrolling(false);

        setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 14f);
            setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE); 
    }
}
```

(As you can see, the width settings are exactly the same as in the template XML).
In Java code I add a topic followed by a "body". These are the methods. (Everything works fine but the text is not wrapped.):

```
private void addTopic(String text)  {
    TopicTableRow topicTableRow = new TopicTableRow(this);
    TopicTextView topicTextView = new TopicTextView(this);

    topicTextView.setText(text);

    topicTableRow.addView(topicTextView);
    messageTable.addView(topicTableRow);        
}

private void addStandardText()  {
    TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this);
    BodyTextView bodyTextView = new BodyTextView(this);

    bodyTextView.setText(getString(R.string.standardText));

    tableRow.addView(bodyTextView);
    messageTable.addView(tableRow);
}
```

I have the suspicion that the line `setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));` of BodyTextView doesn't work properly because when I set layoutWidth to 100 or 200, the width won't be minimized and protrudes out of the screen. Why is this so? If I try shortening the topic to 200 (TopicTextView), I get a smaller bar, so the Java method should work properly, but in BodyTextView it somehow ignores the width. Does anybody have any idea why this is so? I already thought about [this bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=12244) but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved: 
I don't know why but...

**setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT|InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE);**

instead of

**setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE);**

does the job.

Answer (score 0):

instead of 
 
android:stretchColumns="*"`

 use 

android:shrinkcolumns="0"

or refer this link: http://android-pro.blogspot.com/2010/02/table-layout.html

Comment: What is the target of this in my case? When I shrink the table, all columns have the same size as the widest content. Moreover, the text isn't wrapped either.